# How to put header file to .tab.h in Bison?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, bison

I wrote bison code header:

```
%{
#include "foo.h"
%}
```

And I defined a struct named 'Foo' in header. I'd like to use it as token type in Bison.

```
%define api.value.type union
%token <Foo*> bar
```

Then I use `-d` option to generate `bison.tab.h` file.

```
bison -d bison.y
```

But there is no `#include foo.h` in `bison.tab.h`, and it use struct Foo to define the union YYSTYPE.

```
//bison.tab.h
union YYSTPE {
    Foo* bar;
    ...
};
```

It caused error when compile this program: `error: ‘Foo’ does not name a type`

Is there a way to include header file in `bison.tab.h` or another solution of this case?

Comment: can you share your bison.y ?

Comment: What you put between `%{` and `%}` is not processed by Bison, it is copied straight into the generated C (or C++) source file. You can not put Bison-specific statements in a header file that way.

Comment: "*But there is no #include foo.h in bison.tab.h*" <= please show (at least the top of) your `foo.h` and `bison.y`. Because from what's currently given, this is how it's done.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

For includes that should appear in both the .c and the .h file (before the definition for the `%union`), you should use `%code requires { ... }`. `%{ ...  }` inserts code in the .c file only.

For more information on the various `%code` options, you can look at the ["Prologue Alternatives" chapter of the Bison docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Prologue-Alternatives.html#Prologue-Alternatives).

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use 2.3 bison version, which doesn't have %code directive, so I just added a command which insert my include into top of bison output header, when I compile program

```
echo #include \"my_include.hpp\" | cat - ${BISON_HEADER_OUTPUT} > tmp && mv tmp ${BISON_HEADER_OUTPUT}
```